# ElasticSearch automatically converting field type inside Java Map from String to date when saving

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following index mapping - a field called `customFields` contains other fields such as `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.

```
{
  "customFields": {
    "properties": {
      "firstName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "dateOfBirth": {
        "type": "date"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

In my Spring project, `customFields` is a `Map<String, Object>`.

The `dateOfBirth` field accepts values in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and is a `String`.

However, when its being saved on ElasticSearch, the type becomes `date`. I have been debugging and I haven't found anywhere in the application where the `dateOfBirth` type changes to date before being sent to ElasticSearch.

Is it possible ElasticSearch changes the type by itself in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining the Elasticsearch mapping explicitly for these fields, and when Elasticsearch see them it tries to match them with best data types, as your `dateOfBirth` is having a `YYYY-MM-DD` even if its enclosed in "" and you want them to be a `text` field, Elasticsearch maps it to `date` field due to its value.

if you want to avoid this, you need to define  `dateOfBirth` explicitly with `text` data type in your Elasticsearch index mapping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. If the index mapping has already been created and `dateOfBirth` is mapped to `date`, is there a way to update the index mapping through the console?

Comment: @murohima_1, you can't change the datatype of an existing field, but you can add a new field, by using update mapping API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping, this way new data will have a correct mapping or if you have a less data, just create a fresh index

Comment: As you said, ElasticSearch does an automatic mapping based on the field's value. I found a way to disable the date_detection here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection

However, when I run the PUT query to disable the date_detection, it returns an error saying the index already exists

Comment: @murohima_1 yes, like you can't change the data type, seems like you can't change this setting once index is created.. i would suggest you to start from fresh

Comment: Upvoted but I need a few more reputation for it show up. Marked the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I posted another question which is kind of related to this one. Can you please check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220153/elasticsearch-spring-disable-date-detection-only-for-a-set-of-fields-and-not-t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244708/discussion-between-amit-and-murohima-1).