# ElasticSearch Spring - disable date_detection only for a set of fields and not the entire index using @Mapping annotation

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to disable date_detection on a set of fields in an index. Below is the mapping

```
{
  "my-index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_class" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "customFields" : {
          "properties" : {
            "firstName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "lastName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "address" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "dateOfBirth" : {
              "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "key" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "updatedDate" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "basic_date_time"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the `dateOfBirth` field to be of type `text`, not `date`.

So I did the following:

I created a `mappings.json` file (see below) and used the @Mapping(mappingPath = "mappings.json") annotation

```
{
  "date_detection": false
}
```

Now, this does disable `date_detection` but it also forces the `updatedDate` to be of type `text` and this is causing some errors.

These are the `updatedDate` and `customFields` variables in my index class:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
Instant updatedDate;

Map<String, Object> customFields;
```

Is there a way to disable `date_detection` for the fields inside `customFields` so that only the `dateOfBirth` field's type is changed to `text` and not `updatedDate`?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/dynamic-field-mapping.html#_disabling_date_detection *date_detection* is per index and not configurable for individual fields.

If you use a mappings file, Spring Data Elasticsearch does not create a mapping from the entity but only uses the file, so your `@Field` annotation is ignored.

Keep the `@Field` annotation on the `updatedDate` and add

```java
@Mapping(dateDetection = Mapping.Detection.FALSE)
```

to your entity class (the one annotated with `@Document`). Remove the reference to the mapping.json.

Comment: I am using an older library version (4.0.0) which does not have the @Mapping annotation with date_detection. Updating to a newer version (4.3) is causing a lot of issues in the project because of Aggregations & AggregationContainers.

Comment: It appears the dateDetected attribute is only available for newer versions of Spring Data ElasticSearch.  Is there a comparable way to accomplish this with Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.0.4?

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by P.J. Meisch works great. However older versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch don't contain the `dateDetection` attribute of the `@Mapping` annotation. If you can't upgrade Spring Data Elasticsearch, you can annotate fields with:

`@Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)`

This will prevent Elasticsearch from inferring the data type of a text field based on it's value and mapping it as a date if it contains data in a common date format. This is useful if you have a String field with records that may sometimes contain data that is in a valid date format and other times not. In those situations, the automatic mapping of fields based on value is problematic because if the first value indexed by Elastic happens to be a valid date format, it will map the field as a date. Subsequent records that are indexed that do not contain valid date data will be rejected since they can't be parsed as a date.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations), the `store` attribute is used to "Flag whether the original field value should be store in Elasticsearch, default value is false". So while the name of the attribute may lead one to believe it's used to mark a field as transient or something similar, it appears it's actually used to tell Elastic to just index the field value verbatim rather than evaluating the value to infer it's type.

Comment: the `store` parameter of `@Field` directly maps to Elasticsearch's `store` mapping parameter, it has nothing to do with how Elasticsearch parses or interprets a field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html)

Comment: That is interesting. Can you explain why annotating a string field that was being interpreted as a date with `@Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)` made Elasticsearch stop mapping the field as a date?  I have verified multiple times that if I remove `store = true` the field starts being mapped as a date again. I am guessing that I stumbled upon an unintended consequence of `store = true`?

Comment: did you delete and recreate the index with Spring Data Elasticsearch? or call explicitly `putMapping()`? Spring Data Elasticsearch only writes the mapping when you are using repositories and the index does not yet exist.  Btw, Elasticsearch does not allow to change the mapping of a field after it is defined once.

Comment: I deleted the index then let Spring Data Elasticsearch re-create it.